# Azure Kubernetes Service - Persistent Volume using Disk on another tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-disk

For AKS to use a azure disk for persistent storage, we can define a persistentVolumeClaim as follows -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azure-managed-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: default
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Is it possible to use an azure disk from another tenant B for use as persistentVolume for an AKS in tenant A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible.

I guess you will have to migrate your disks into the Subscription AKS is running in. You can then use the existing disk as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume#mount-disk-as-volume).